# How to set the dependency between two trigger pipelines in azure synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-link

I have a two trigger synapse pipelines one which is scheduled at 03 am cst , What I'm looking now is the Second pipeline should trigger after the completion of the first pipeline i.e after 03 am cst.

Is there a way i can create this dependency in the synapse. If yes please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options:

1. Create an event trigger for the 2nd pipeline and add a copy file activity at the end of 1st pipeline. So whenever the 1st pipeline gets completed, it would generate a file and trigger the 2nd pipeline
2. Use execute pipeline activity at the end of 1st pipeline and trigger the 2nd pipeline ( you can even use web activity but there would be additional efforts for it)

Comment: Can we create a tumbling trigger depdendency?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a [tumbling window trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-tumbling-window-trigger?tabs=data-factory%2Cazure-powershell) for both pipelines.
2. While creating a tumbling window trigger for the second pipeline, you can add a dependency trigger under Advance property and select pipeline1 trigger.
3. The second trigger runs only upon completion of the dependency trigger.